# Acumatica - Different PXUIField names for the same field in the same graph for different tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I have a page containing several tabs, with the common graph. The problem is that I use one particular field in two tabs and what if the customer needs to display them with different names on each tab?
Here's my DAC:

```
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product Foo")]
    public virtual string ProductFoo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProductFoo;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProductFoo = value;
        }
    }
```

More particularly, what if I need to name this field not "Product Foo" but "Product Bar" on the second tab?

I can't do it with

```
protected void Product_ProductFoo_CacheAttached(PXCache sender){}
```

because as I've already mentioned, they use the common graph.

So is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you create an additional DAC for each tab data view such as

```
[Serializable]
public class Product2 : Product 
{
    public new abstract class productFoo: PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product Foo 2")]
    public override string ProductFoo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProductFoo;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProductFoo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to update your view to use Product2, Product3, etc. for each addtional DAC class used for each tab.

Comment: Really nice solution. Appreciate that!

Comment: Glad it worked. You should also be able to use cache attached if needed such as... protected void Product2_ProductFoo_CacheAttached(PXCache sender){}